# Can I keep my desktop settings exactly as they are now if I upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, accessibility

I have severe OCD and would like some help regarding changes to my desktop if I upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I use the gnome classic (no effects) desktop. The desktop has nothing on it - it is black and I have changed the top panel to black as I like things to be clear and the gnome icon within the panel appears only when I move my arrow to the top left of the screen (because I have hidden it) which is perfect for me.

Now, I see that the new release includes the gnome classic desktop - will those settings I have described above be kept in the new release as I don't want to go through these things again because of my condition. Please give me any advice as this is important to me.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you upgrade via the internet, and use the same desktop environment to log in, your settings will be preserved.

The settings are stored in your home folder so once this is not deleted you will be okay.
If you do a fresh install however, you will lose your settings.